# PyGTK radio buttons are all checked

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gedit

I'm trying to create a Window using PyGTK that has dynamically created radio buttons based of an array of Strings (an a array that looks like ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"] would create 3 radio buttons with labels respective to the array elements).

My problem is that all the Radio buttons are checked, they cannot be unchecked, and therefore I can't connect to the "toggled" event.  I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
class SelectionWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        global options
        super(EmulatorSelectionWindow, self).__init__()
        self.set_title("Select an Emulator")
        box = Gtk.VBox(spacing=10)
        group = Gtk.RadioButton(None, "test radio")
        box.pack_start(group, True,True, 0)
        for option in options:
            r = Gtk.RadioButton(group, option)
            r.connect("toggled", self.on_radio_selection, option)
            print "before setting active", r.get_active()
            r.set_active(False)
            print "after setting active", r.get_active()
            box.pack_start(r,True, True, 0)
        self.add(box)

    def on_radio_selection(self, widget, data=None):
        print "toggle pressed", data
```

The print statements that call get_active(), always print True

[Edit]
I am loading the Gtk by

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

[image: This is my window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that in newer version you have use static method [Gtk.RadioButton.new_with_label_from_widget](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/button_widgets.html#Gtk.RadioButton.new_with_label_from_widget) instead of the method you are using currently to create radio button (which works fine for pygtk 2.0 versions). Try changing `Gtk.RadioButton` to `Gtk.RadioButton.new_with_label_from_widget` in the code.
Hope this helps!